# Remove experimental branch

Tags: mercurial, branch

How do I remove a feature branch in mercurial if I want to remove it completely? It should be stripped from the history and I don't want to merge the changes in another branch (just throw the code away).

I know that I can clone my other branches to a new repository like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7463712/851737) but that does not seem to be a clean solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove changesets from a Mercurial repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520697/how-to-remove-changesets-from-a-mercurial-repository)

Comment: @TimHenigan The solution is the same, but it is a completely different workflow and the reason why I didn't find it in the first place. I am not sure how this should be handled on SO. It might be OK closing this question because a search with this keywords will no link to the solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a working solution [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PruningDeadBranches#Using_strip).

It works by using `hg strip` from the `mq` extension:

```
$ hg strip my_pruned_branch
```

As mentioned in the comments, this should only be used for unpublished changesets.

Comment: Are any of these change sets pushed elsewhere? Strip should only be used for unpublished change sets.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Thanks, I knew that already but pointed it out for others in the answer.

Comment: please update your answer and say how to setup extensions strip [extensions]
strip =